# Is there an API for sharing an attachment in RingCentral Glip?

Tags: share, attachment, ringcentral, glip

I want to build an app that can monitor one Glip team for posts including screenshots and then post that message to another Glip team. I can read a post, download an attachment and repost / upload it, but is there a way to simply share an existing attachment without reposting it. This can be done in the app UI but I didn't see a share API in the Glip API Reference.

Here's the Glip API Reference which includes endpoints for creating, reading, updating and deleting posts but not sharing:

- https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/team-messaging

The icon for sharing is the 6th from the left in the app screenshot below.

[image: RingCentral Glip buttons]

Is there a way to do this in Glip without downloading and re-uploading the file?

Comment: Below are the useful links.
https://medium.com/ringcentral-developers/announcing-enhanced-posting-with-glip-attachments-and-the-glip-file-upload-api-25e0ac5c72ce

https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/idea/772/new-glip-features-post-attachments-and-the-file-up.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share an attachment via the Glip API, create a new post with an existing attachment.

**Create Post API**

The Create Post API takes an optional `attachments` array which references existing attachments. Both the `id` and `type` properties are required. Both properties are present in the post API response.

```
POST /restapi/v1.0/glip/chats/{chatId}/posts

{
    "text": "Please check out this file",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "id":"123456789",
            "type":"File"
        }
    ]
}
```

- Ref: https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Posts/createGlipPost

**Example Get Posts API**

The following is an example of a post showing the attachments array with the `id` and `type` properties. The attachment URL is an AWS Presigned Object URL as shown below.

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/glip/chats/{chatId}/posts

{
    "records": [
        {
            "id": "11111111",
            "creatorId": "22222222",
            "creationTime": "2019-08-26T21:41:56.648Z",
            "lastModifiedTime": "2019-08-26T21:41:56.648Z",
            "type": "TextMessage",
            "chatId": "33333333",
            "mentions": [],
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "id": "123456789",
                    "name": "sharedfile.png",
                    "contentUri": "https://glip-vault-1.s3.amazonaws.com/web/customer_files/44444444/testimage.png?Expires=55555555&AWSAccessKeyId=myAccessKeyId&Signature=myAWSPresignedObjectUrlSignature",
                    "type": "File"
                }
            ],
            "text": "Check this out!"
        }
    },
    "navigation": {}
}
```

- Ref: https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Posts/readGlipPosts

**Sharing Permissions**

Attachments can only be shared by the original poster or within the same chat. If a different user wants to share an attachment in a different team, it will be necessary to download and repost the file, generating a new attachment id.

If a different user attempts to share an attachment in a different chat, a `403 Forbidden` error will be encountered:

```
403 Forbidden

{
    "errors": [
        {
            "errorCode": "PST-011",
            "message": "The requester must be attachment creator or attachment must belong to the requested chat."
        }
    ]
}
```